# How to check textfield input text with decimal point

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I want to check number text range 0~20 with decimal point.
Like 0.01 & 19.99 
How to prevent user input 001 or 02......ect.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        guard let text = textField.text as NSString? else { return false }
        let finalText = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        if finalText.isEmpty { return true }
        if finalText.first == "0" && finalText.prefix(2) == "0." { return true }
        
        guard let num = Double(finalText), num <= 20, num >= 0 else {
            return false
        }
    
        let numString = String(format: "%.2f", num)
        if finalText.count > numString.count {
            return false
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to check the pattern.

```
func checkPattern(for text: String) -> Bool {
    let regexExp = "^(\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2})$"
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexExp)
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: range)
    return matches.first != nil
}
```

I have defined the regex pattern `"^(\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2})$"` that will only accept one or two digits before the decimal point and one or two digits after the decimal point.

You can use it in your code like:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        guard let text = textField.text as NSString? else { return false }
        let finalText = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        if finalText.isEmpty { return true }
        
        guard let num = Double(finalText), num <= 20, num >= 0 else {
            return false
        }

        // this func will return true if it matches your desired pattern
        if !checkPattern(for: finalText){ 
            return false
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

Hope it solves your problem.